# How to include config files from multiple projects into an Eclipse project's spring nature?

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-nature

using Eclipse Helios, and the Spring Source Tool Suite 2.8.1.201111221000-RELEASE, having two Eclipse projects with a Spring nature added, the second depending on the first - is there a way to add Spring bean configuration files from *both* projects to the "Spring/Bean Support" configuration of the second project?

In detail, say

- project A builds some `a.jar`, containing some `module.xml` file, declaring some Spring beans implemented in A.
- project B builds some `b.jar`, containing some `application.xml` file, declaring the beans implemented in B
- B's spring configuration references some beans which are declared in A's configuration
- `application.xml` does not import `module.xml`, instead, at runtime an `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` is created which loads (all) configurations files from the classpath which match a certain pattern (something like `"classpath:application.xml","classpath*:module.xml"`)
- B's spring nature is configured to use `application.xml` as config file (Project properties => Spring => Beans Support => Config Files)

What I want to do is to tell STS that B's spring configuration consists not only of B's `application.xml`, but also of A's `module.xml`. If A is not part of the workspace, but `a.jar` is located in my Maven repo, with B declared to depend on that artifact, I can add the `module.xml` config file to B's spring configuration. If, however, A is part of the workspace, referencing its `module.xml` does not seem to be possible.

Do I miss something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I *did* miss something! You can't add `module.xml` to B's "Spring / Beans Support / Config Files" list - but when you edit a particular Config Set (second tab page), then - surprise! - all of module A's config files are available, too.

works like a charm ...